# Incrementing the size of a Binary Search Tree when string is inserted

Tags: c++, insert, segmentation-fault, size, binary-search-tree

I am attempting to insert into an a Binary Search Tree. I am currently getting a SIGSEGV Segmentation fault error whenever I am incrementing the size of my tree. What is my problem? How could I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Public in my header file:

```
bool insert(const Comparable & x)
{
    insert(x, root);
}
int size(const Comparable & x)
{
    size(x, root);
}
```

Private in my header file:

```
private:
    struct BinaryNode
    {
        Comparable key;
        BinaryNode *left;
        BinaryNode *right;
        vector<int> lineNumberList;
        int size;

        BinaryNode(const Comparable & thekey, BinaryNode *lt, BinaryNode *rt)
        : key{ thekey }, left{ lt }, right{ rt } { }

        BinaryNode(Comparable && thekey, BinaryNode *lt, BinaryNode *rt)
        : key{ move(thekey)}, left{ lt }, right{ rt } { }
    };




    int size(BinaryNode *t)
    {
        if (t == NULL)
            return 0;
        else
          return (t->left->size) + 1 + (t->right->size);
    }



    bool insert(const Comparable & x, BinaryNode *t){
        if (t == NULL)
        {
          root = new BinaryNode{ x, NULL, NULL };
          t->size++; **Segmentation fault**
          return true;
        }
        else if (x < t->key)
        {
        insert(x, t->left);
            if (insert(x, t->left)){
                t->size++; **Segmentation fault**
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        else if (x == t->key)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            insert(x, t->right);
            if (insert(x, t->right)){
                t->size++; **Segmentation fault**
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
     }
```

Comment: What did you notice when stepping through your program line by line using the debugger?

Comment: Also: How do you ensure that `left` and `right` are not `NULL` in this line `(t->left->size) + 1 + (t->right->size);`

Comment: When I stepped through my program using gdb I got:          `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401bbf in BinarySearchTree<std::string>::insert (this=0x7fffffffe390,
    x="1628879936", t=0x0) at BinarySearchTree.h:437
437    t->size++;`                                     Here are the variable values                                 `(gdb) print t
$1 = (BinarySearchTree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::BinaryNode *) 0x0
(gdb) print t.size()
Cannot access memory at address 0x30`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to modify `t->size` while t is NULL. A blind guess without knowing about your design is that if t is NULL, t becomes the new root, so you should make  `t=new BinaryNode{ x, NULL, NULL };` instead of `root=new BinaryNode{ x, NULL, NULL };`

You also increment the size of the struct without initialization, and that's bad, you should make `t->size=1;` instead.